# Netbeans Java code suggestion options/plugin?

Tags: netbeans

If I type `Car.Mile` and press ctrl-spacebar to autocomplete the member name, it does not bring up matches that don't begin with `Mile` at all. This is pretty annoying because so many methods are prefixed with get/set/is like `getMileage()` and `setMileage()`.

[image]

My code completion options look like this currently. Not seeing this as a choice. This is JMonkeyEngine's version of Netbeans, if that matters.

Anyway to get this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the settings for "All Languages" use the **Java** settings:

[image: NetBeans Java completion settings]

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question to show the Java specific menu I see. It's probably JMonkey's fault, I'll have to try it with unmodified netbeans.

Comment: @gunfulker Which NetBeans version is that? The "Subword completion" has been there since at least 8.0

Comment: It's the modified Netbeans that JMonkey uses. It lets you view 3D images as resources and has the LWJGL (opengl for java) libraries attached by default, etc. The "About" section doesn't say what version it's based off of.